# I need to web scrap a particular value from a page which is contained in a table

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, python-requests

I want to scrap net sales value for Dec 2021 that is contained in a table from a webpage. I am using simple beautifulsoup module.I have included the python code I am using for extracting some of the other values.I want to extract the value 9644.8. The code for the webpage is give below

```html
<table class="table table-sm table-hover screenertable  table-responsive-sm">
    <thead>
    <tr>
        <th scope="col">PARTICULARS</th>
        <th scope="col">Dec 2020</th>
        <th scope="col">Mar 2021</th>
        <th scope="col">Jun 2021</th>
        <th scope="col">Sep 2021</th>
        <th scope="col">Dec 2021</th>
    </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
    <tr class="">
        <th scope="row">Net Sales <span class="infolink" data-tooltip="tooltip" title=""
                                        data-original-title="It is companys core revenue net of discounts and returns."><svg
                class="svg-inline--fa fa-info-circle fa-w-16" aria-hidden="true" focusable="false" data-prefix="fas"
                data-icon="info-circle" role="img" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 512 512"
                data-fa-i2svg=""><path fill="currentColor"
                                       d="M256 8C119.043 8 8 119.083 8 256c0 136.997 111.043 248 248 248s248-111.003 248-248C504 119.083 392.957 8 256 8zm0 110c23.196 0 42 18.804 42 42s-18.804 42-42 42-42-18.804-42-42 18.804-42 42-42zm56 254c0 6.627-5.373 12-12 12h-88c-6.627 0-12-5.373-12-12v-24c0-6.627 5.373-12 12-12h12v-64h-12c-6.627 0-12-5.373-12-12v-24c0-6.627 5.373-12 12-12h64c6.627 0 12 5.373 12 12v100h12c6.627 0 12 5.373 12 12v24z"></path></svg>
            <!-- <i class="fas fa-info-circle"></i> --></span></th>
        <td>
            <span class="Number" value="10824.4">10,824.40</span>
        </td>
        <td>
            <span class="Number" value="9530.9">9,530.90</span>
        </td>
        <td>
            <span class="Number" value="9088.2">9,088.20</span>
        </td>
        <td>
            <span class="Number" value="9321.5">9,321.50</span>
        </td>
        <td>
            <span class="Number" value="9644.8">9,644.80</span>
        </td>
    </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

```py
import pandas as pd
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests
a=input("Enter symbol of the company\n")
url="https://ticker.finology.in/company/"+a
print(url)
response=requests.get(url)
soup=BeautifulSoup(response.text,'html.parser')
CP = soup.find("div", {"id":"mainContent_clsprice"}).find("span", {"class": "Number"}).getText()
```

The ticker I am using is IDEA

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can pass the URL directly to [`pandas.read_html()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.read_html.html) which will return a list of dataframes of tables found.

```
>>> dfs = pd.read_html('https://ticker.finology.in/company/idea')
>>> dfs[1]
          PARTICULARS  Dec 2020  Mar 2021  Jun 2021  Sep 2021  Dec 2021
0           Net Sales  10824.40   9530.90   9088.20    9321.5    9644.8
1   Total Expenditure   6717.40   5296.20   5529.30    5672.9    5995.2
2    Operating Profit   4107.00   4234.70   3558.90    3648.6    3649.6
3        Other Income     36.30     31.10     29.20      22.8      25.2
4            Interest   4782.60   4711.00   5223.20    5112.8    5324.7
5        Depreciation   5638.90   5629.50   5831.90    5743.8    5550.5
6   Exceptional Items   -439.50   -972.60     51.30      13.5      11.6
7   Profit Before Tax  -6717.70  -7047.30  -7415.70   -7171.7   -7188.8
8                 Tax      0.00    -20.80      0.00       0.0       0.0
9    Profit After Tax  -6717.70  -7026.50  -7415.70   -7171.7   -7188.8
10  Adjusted EPS (Rs)     -2.34     -2.45     -2.58      -2.5      -2.5
```

Comment: Thank you for your response. I need only the value of net sales in the last coloumn that would be the latest value of net sales. Can you please help in what could be done in that scenario

Comment: You can use `.loc` e.g. `dfs[1].loc[0, 'Dec 2021']`

Comment: Thank you sir, it worked, I used iloc as I needed the last column and the first row for my reference

Answer (score 0):

Provided you have located the correct table you can use `select_one` and the css selector `tbody td:last-child > .Number`.  `tbody` will restrict to the table body rows, `select_one` with `td:last-child` will grab the first last column, then the `> .Number` will grab the direct child `span`. You could of course, combine and shorten the selector list rather than separately grabbing table, however, I was unsure if you would do other things with the table.

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs
import requests

r = requests.get('https://ticker.finology.in/company/idea', headers = {'User-Agent':'Mozilla/5.0'})
soup = bs(r.content, 'lxml')
table = soup.select_one('.card:has(> #mainContent_hfSizeForQuarter) table')
table.select_one('tbody td:last-child > .Number').text.strip()
```